# Which Ubuntu kernel package should I run in a Xen domU

Tags: server, kernel, virtualization, xen

I have a Xen domU provided by a 3rd party vendor, and am running Ubuntu 10.04 on it. Is there a more xen-specific kernel I am running than that provided by the `linux-image-2.6.32-21-server` package? I note there is an equivalent `-virtual` package, but I have the `linux-virtual` package installed and my kernel is still happily -server.

```
james@nephos:~$ uname -a
Linux nephos 2.6.32-21-server #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 09:17:34 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Should I be looking to install the `-virtual` image directly (contrary to the package description?)

The background to this is that we're seeing some performance issues, and now suddenly some FS corruption issues on an ext3 filesystem running on a Xen virtual block device, and the vendor have asked me if we're running a Xen-specific kernel -- I installed using their supplied image/installer, but they primarily recommend/support CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the 10.04 -server kernel supports pvops (http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/XenParavirtOps) and so you don't need a special kernel to run it as a domU.

From the link above:

"Ubuntu 10.04 ("Lucid Lynx") also includes Xen PV domU kernel."